# Рваные края background

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Друзья! Как реализовать на css данный эффект? Верх заливаем цветом, низ картинка

[image]

Comment: Вот статья, задача решается только при помощи css. Возможно кому то поможет :)
http://habrahabr.ru/post/176591/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Этот рваный кусочек шириной ~ 30px добавляется бэкграундом к псевдоэлементу, которому задается абсолютная отрицательная позиция.
Дабы не плодить лишние дивы.

Comment: Делать при помощи ::after? Если можно, пример кода напишите, не разобрался еще в этом элементе)
т.е. при помощи свойств css этот "узор" не сделать?

Comment: При помощи css сделать, через svg можно, но самый простой и боевой метод, без понтов это да.   
Сверху картинку делаю фоном в before, внизу в after, или как удобней, это не принципиально.   

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/5pmmU/  
Синий - родитель.  
У картинок белые поля - это из-за того, что они часть изображения.  
Черный - блок.  

"рваные края" - находятся за границей блока, что позволяет использовать весь его размер, если же можно сделать отступ, то задаете top и bottom 0 у after и before

Comment: извиняюсь, content сделайте только не 123, а "", ну или тогда размер шрифта 0 и прозрачный.

Answer (score 3):

Добрый вечер. Обычно такие эффекты реализуются повторением одного и того же элемента. То есть рисуется кусочек повторяющийся и подставляем к нужному элементу свойство:

```
backgound: url(example/img.gif) repeat x;
```

где url(..) - путь к картинке, repeat x / repeat y / repeat - повторение фона по горизонтали / вертикали / во всех направлениях

Answer (score 2):

[Вот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/35aK3/) вертикального `div`'а, который залит цветом `#E1DFE0`

```html
<svg id="svgelem" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                   

    <polyline points="10 0, 0 10, 10 20, 0 30, 10 40, 0 50, 10 60, 0 70, 10 80, 0 90, 10 100, 0 110, 10 120, 0 130, 10 140, 0 150, 10 160, 0 170, 10 180, 0 190, 10 200, 0 210, 10 220, 0 230, 10 240, 0 250, 10 260, 0 270, 10 280, 0 290, 10 300, 0 310, 10 320, 0 330, 10 340, 0 350, 10 360, 0 370, 10 380, 0 390, 10 400, 0 410, 10 420, 0 430, 10 440, 0 450, 10 460, 0 470, 10 480, 0 490, 10 500, 0 510, 10 520, 0 530, 10 540, 0 550, 10 560, 0 570, 10 580, 0 590, 10 600, 0 610, 10 620, 0 630, 10 640, 0 650, 10 660, 0 670, 10 680, 0 690, 10 700, 0 710, 10 720, 0 730, 10 740, 0 750, 10 760, 0 770, 10 780, 0 790, 10 800, 0 810, 10 820, 0 830, 10 840, 0 850, 10 860, 0 870, 10 880, 0 890, 10 900, 0 910, 10 920, 0 930, 10 940, 0 950, 10 960, 0 970, 10 980, 0 990, 10 1000, 0 1010, 10 1020, 0 1030, 10 1040, 0 1050, 10 1060, 0 1070, 10 1080, 0 1090, 10 1100, 0 1110, 10 1120, 0 1130, 10 1140, 0 1150, 10 1160, 0 1170, 10 1180, 0 1190, 10 1200, 0 1210, 10 1220, 0 1230, 10 1240, 0 1250, 10 1260, 0 1270, 10 1280, 0 1290, 10 1300, 0 1310, 10 1320, 0 1330, 10 1340, 0 1350, 10 1360, 0 1370, 10 1380, 0 1390, 10 1400, 0 1410, 10 1420, 0 1430, 10 1440, 0 1450, 10 1460, 0 1470, 10 1480, 0 1490, 10 1500, 0 1510, 10 1520, 0 1530, 10 1540, 0 1550, 10 1560, 0 1570, 10 1580, 0 1590, 10 1600, 0 1610, 10 1620, 0 1630, 10 1640, 0 1650, 10 1660, 
    
    0 1670, 10 1680, 0 1690, 10 1700, 0 1710, 10 1720, 0 1730, 10 1740, 0 1750, 10 1760, 0 1770, 10 1780, 0 1790, 10 1800, 0 1810, 10 1820, 0 1830, 10 1840, 0 1850, 10 1860, 0 1870, 10 1880, 0 1890, 10 1900, 0 1910, 10 1920, 0 1930, 10 1940, 0 1950, 10 1960, 0 1970, 10 1980, 0 1990, 10 2000, 40 2000, 40 0, 10 0" fill="#E1DFE0"></polyline>
```

Comment: Да вы батенька совсем не ленивый!